# forEach inside forEach with a condition?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, foreach

I have two lists and I want to check if list B contains items from list A, so I have created a button that triggers a forEach to check if any of list B's elements' innerText is similar to  the ones in list A:

```
    let itemsFromA = document.querySelectorAll('.itemA')
    let listB = document.getElementById('listB')

    listB.childNodes.forEach(childNodes => {
        if (childNodes.innerText === itemsFromA.forEach(itemsFromA => itemsFromA.innerText)) {
            childNodes.style.display = 'none'
        }
    })
}
```

But nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how your buttons are setup in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

`NodeList.forEach()` doesn't return anything (or always returns `undefined`). Use `Array.from()` to convert the `itemsFromA` to an array, and `Array.some()` to check if any item has the same `innerText`:

```
let itemsFromA = document.querySelectorAll('.itemA')
let listB = document.getElementById('listB')

listB.childNodes.forEach(node => {
  if (Array.from(itemsFromA).some(itemsFromA => itemsFromA.innerText === node.innerTex)) {
    node.style.display = 'none'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **some** instead of **forEach** (which doesn't return anything, hence your code isn't working..).

**some** will test whether or not at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```
let itemsFromA = document.querySelectorAll('.itemA')
let listB = document.getElementById('listB')

new_list = listB.childNodes.map((index, childNodes) => {
    if (itemsFromA.some(item => item.innerText === childNodes.innerText)) {
        childNodes.style.display = 'none'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `forEach` loop doesn't return values.
Use map instead of forEach for expected behaviour.

eg :

```js
if (childNodes.innerText === itemsFromA.map(itemsFromA => itemsFromA.innerText))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
  let itemsFromA = document.querySelectorAll('.itemA')
  let listB = document.getElementById('listB')

  list = listB.childNodes.map((index, childNodes) => {
      itemsFromA.forEach(itemsFromA => {
        if (childNodes.innerText === itemsFromA.innerText)
           childNodes.style.display = 'none'
      })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach does not return any value, it will only loop through the array. you should use find function instead

`let itemsFromA = document.querySelectorAll('.itemA')
let listB = document.getElementById('listB')

```
listB.childNodes.forEach(childNode => {
    if (itemsFromA.find(itemsFromA => itemsFromA.innerText == childNode.innerText)) {
        childNodes.style.display = 'none'
    }
})
```

}`